# Migrating Ushahidi CMS to a new Server

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, migrate

I just installed [Ushahidi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ushahidi) on my server, configured the site an create some users an reports. **Now, I want to migrate my platform from my “localhost” server, to a new “public” server**, **I think, what I should do is to migrate my Ushahidi database to the new server, and then copy my Ushahidi folder**.
I am not pretty sure about it, so i ask for your help an wise answer, maybe some of you have performed this task before and could give me some tips an light my way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out a way to perform the task, just create a SQL script to export my database to the new server, then installed all the php-apache modules i need, copy my application folder into the new web server directory, restart the server and VOILA it works!